# Nvidia settings won't take hold

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

I have two monitors, and I prefer to have the monitor on the right hand side to have the Gnome panels on it. I think this is called the "primary display".

Every time I reboot, the monitor on the left is set to be the primary display. So, I go into the Nvidia X Server Settings interface, go under Xserver Display Configuration, where I click on the right hand monitor, and then click the check box to make it the primary display. I then click to "Save to X configuration file", and after prompting me to enter my root password, it seems to save.

But, then, when I reboot, the primary display is on the left again.

How do I make the setting stick so that the right hand monitor stays set as the primary display?

[image: Xserver settings]

Comment: In terminal sudo nvidia-settings and then save to x configuration file.

Comment: @ArupRoyChowdhury, Thank you for responding. Unfortunately, the command you suggest did not produce any results different than what I describe in the question.

Comment: Try setting "Include X Display Names in the Config File" from "nvidia-settings Configuration" tab. then "Save to X configuration File" again.

Comment: @Sneetsher, thank you for responding. Unfortunately, that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I also have this problem